# Sphinx Error - WARNING "list-table" widths do not match the number of columns in table (1)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm working with Sphinx and the python Sphinx syntax is:

```
.. list-table:: Frozen Delights!
    :widths: 15 10 30 20
    :header-rows: 1

    * - Treat
        - Quantity
        - Description
    * - Albatross
        - 2.99
        - On a stick!
    * - Crunchy Frog
        - 1.49
        - If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be
        crunchy, now would it?
    * - Gannet Ripple
        - 1.99
        - On a stick!
```

I keep getting the error when trying to generate the .rst file: `WARNING "list-table" widths do not match the number of columns in table (1)`. I've tried several other examples from Sphinx documentation and several others, nothing appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

The example given in [docutils documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#list-table) works for me.

Compare your example to the published one, and note indentation, the number of `widths` arguments, and how you wrap the long line differ.

```
.. list-table:: Frozen Delights!
   :widths: 15 10 30
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Treat
     - Quantity
     - Description
   * - Albatross
     - 2.99
     - On a stick!
   * - Crunchy Frog
     - 1.49
     - If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be
       crunchy, now would it?
   * - Gannet Ripple
     - 1.99
     - On a stick!
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really answer your original question, but I'm having the same issue and the only solution for me was to switch to the other format supported by Sphinx:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| Header 1   | Header 2   | Header 3  | Header 1   | Header 3  |
+============+============+===========+============+===========+
| body row 1 | column 2   | column 3  | body row 1 | column 3  |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| body row 1 | column 2   | column 3  | body row 1 | column 3  |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| body row 1 | column 2   | column 3  | body row 1 | column 3  |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| body row 1 | column 2   | column 3  | body row 1 | column 3  |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```